# What's the coefficent of $x^{20}$ in $(x^3+x^4+x^5+...)^5$? Only hint is needed.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

I know about Binomial/Multinomial expansion but I got stuck on this series; it doesn't look like anything I've solved before. I already searched for any hint/formula and couldn't find one, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
$$
(x^3+x^4+\cdots+x^n+\cdots)^5=x^{15}(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^5=\frac{x^{15}}{(1-x)^5}\\ =\frac{x^{15}}{3!}\frac{d^4}{dx^4}\frac{1}{1-x}= \frac{x^{15}}{4!}
\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots\right)^{(4)}\\=\frac{x^{15}}{4!}
\left(\frac{4!}{0!}+\frac{5!}{1!}x+\frac{6!}{2!}x^2+\frac{7!}{3!}x^3+\frac{8!}{4!}x^4+\frac{9!}{5!}x^5+\cdots\right)
$$
Hence coefficient of $x^{20}$ is 
$$
c_{20}=\frac{9!}{4!5!}
$$

Note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}, \quad
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}, \quad
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\frac{3!}{(1-x)^4}, \quad 
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(1-x)^n}
$$

Comment: Thank you! Can you clarify the second line a bit? I didn't get what you did there.

Comment: @John the fourth order derivative of $(1-x)^{-1}$ gets you the first expression, and then interpreting $(1-x)^{-1}$ as the sum of a geometric series gets you the second expression (superscript (4) indicates fourth order derivative).

Answer (score 2):

Can be written as

$x^{15}(1-x)^{-5}$

Use binomial expansion for $(1-x)^{-5}$

That is
$$x^{15}(1+5x+ \frac{5 \cdot 6}{2!}x^2 + \frac{5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7}{3!}x^3 + \frac{5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8}{4!}x^4 + \frac{5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9}{5!}x^5 + \cdots)$$

Coefficient of $x^{20}$ is

$x^{15}×$ coefficient of $x^5$ .

Which is $$\frac{5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9}{5!}$$

Comment: This is much simpler and exactly answers my question. Thanks!